# Can a Toyota Venza cabin air filter deteriorate over time?

Tags: toyota, cabin-filter, venza

Our 2016 Venza was allowing a lot of dust into the cabin. When we took it to the dealership, they said a rodent made a hole in the filter, wanted $350 to repair. My husband was shown the filter with a hole right in the middle. He replaced the filter at home, and there was no evidence of a rodent causing the damage. Is it possible that the filter was never actually replaced on a previous visit and the so called damage is just normal deterioration?

Comment: An old filter just deteriorate in on single place leaving the rest fine? Well, possible but never seen it... Usually old filters fall apart all over...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Second to what Solar Mike is saying, most vehicle maintenance recommendations have the cabin air filter changed out at each oil change. $350 to change it out? That's gouging in and of itself. I'm sure you found the replacement to be MUCH cheaper than that.

Comment: Another choice is to leave it out. Cars worked fine for many decades with no interior filters. And my Nissan Titan SLE  ( top trim model) did not contain a filter in the holder because it was not the 4 wheel drive model. I did not realize this for about 30,000 miles. It was simple to put in a filter.

Comment: My Jaguar has a carbon activated filter for the cabin air - you get what you pay for....